# how to create multi-dimensional array from two or more arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have one array which is like this

```
    Array
(
    [sch_name] => example
    [sch_degree] => example
    [sch_field] => example
    [sch_grade] => example
    [sch_from_year] => 2008
    [sch_to_year] => 2008
    [sch_desc] => example
)
```

& more same array like above, Now when i add another array to it, it look like shown below

```
  Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sch_name] => example
            [sch_degree] => example
            [sch_field] => example
            [sch_grade] => example
            [sch_from_year] => 2008
            [sch_to_year] => 2008
            [sch_desc] => example
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sch_name] => example
            [sch_degree] => example
            [sch_field] => example
            [sch_grade] => example
            [sch_from_year] => 2008
            [sch_to_year] => 2008
            [sch_desc] => example
        )

)
```

Now the problem is the third array is appended to the  [1] array like shown below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sch_name] => example
            [sch_degree] => example
            [sch_field] => example
            [sch_grade] => example
            [sch_from_year] => 2008
            [sch_to_year] => 2008
            [sch_desc] => example
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sch_name] => example
                    [sch_degree] => example
                    [sch_field] => example
                    [sch_grade] => example
                    [sch_from_year] => 2008
                    [sch_to_year] => 2008
                    [sch_desc] => example
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [sch_name] => example
                    [sch_degree] => example
                    [sch_field] => example
                    [sch_grade] => example
                    [sch_from_year] => 2008
                    [sch_to_year] => 2008
                    [sch_desc] => example
                )

        )

)
```

i want the new array to be appended as [2] & if add more array then it should be like this [3]

here is how i do this

```
$post = array();
$post['sch_name'] = test_input($sch_name);
$post['sch_degree'] = test_input($sch_degree);
$post['sch_field'] = test_input($sch_field);
$post['sch_grade'] = test_input($sch_grade);
$post['sch_from_year'] = test_input($sch_from_year);
$post['sch_to_year'] = test_input($sch_to_year);
$post['sch_desc'] = test_input($sch_desc);

$newArray = array($post, $array_from_db);
```

$array_from_db is fetched from database as i shown in the beginning of question

Comment: why don't you use `array_push`?

Comment: If `$array_from_db` contains two sub array and new array is `$post`, so simply try this `array_push($array_from_db, $post);` The `$array_from_db` will be updated.

Comment: when i tried $newArray = array_push($in, $post);
print_r($newArray); exit; it printed 8

Comment: you need to `print_r($in);`, cause the `array_push` push the array into the first parameter.

Comment: which variable is that dumps for? newArray? what is array_from_db?

Comment: @Webinan same fields but different data

Comment: @FrayneKonok after array_push($array_from_db, $post); when i print it results in same data that is stored in db new data is not added

Comment: so how can i help you now? 
_If $array_from_db contains two sub array and new array is $post, so simply try this array_push($array_from_db, $post); The $array_from_db will be updated_

Comment: @FrayneKonok $array_from_db contains only one array & $post contains new array i want to add them both

Comment: So what about the second array which contain 2 sub arrays?

Comment: that's because until now i was using this code to add arrays $newArray = array($post, $array_from_db); , see  let make you understand more after combining these two arrays, array looks perfect but when third time i add array $post into $newArray = array($post, $array_from_db); they become sub arrays

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111975/discussion-between-frayne-konok-and-sagar-singh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our discussion we are in this position that you got benefited completely.
[discussion-between-frayne-konok-and-sagar-singh](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111975/discussion-between-frayne-konok-and-sagar-singh), Suppose you have array from database like this:

[Online Check](https://3v4l.org/RBMDD), Must be check.

```
$array_from_db = array(
        array(
            "sch_name" => "example",
            "sch_degree" => "example",
            "sch_field" => "example",
            "sch_grade" => "example",
            "sch_from_year" => "2008",
            "sch_to_year" => "2008",
            "sch_desc" => "example"
        ),
        array(
            "sch_name" => "example",
            "sch_degree" => "example",
            "sch_field" => "example",
            "sch_grade" => "example",
            "sch_from_year" => "2008",
            "sch_to_year" => "2008",
            "sch_desc" => "example"
        )
    );
```

**New Post:**

```
$post = array();
$post['sch_name'] = "example";
$post['sch_degree'] = "example";
$post['sch_field'] = "example";
$post['sch_grade'] = "example";
$post['sch_from_year'] = "2008";
$post['sch_to_year'] = "2008";
$post['sch_desc'] = "example";

array_push($array_from_db, $post);

print_r($array_from_db);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to append values to an array simply use `$array[] = $newArray;` this will add the new item as the last item;

```
$post = array();
$post['sch_name'] = test_input($sch_name);
$post['sch_degree'] = test_input($sch_degree);
$post['sch_field'] = test_input($sch_field);
$post['sch_grade'] = test_input($sch_grade);
$post['sch_from_year'] = test_input($sch_from_year);
$post['sch_to_year'] = test_input($sch_to_year);
$post['sch_desc'] = test_input($sch_desc);

$array_from_db[] = $post;
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need a container array to contain all arrays from db. But

```
$newArray = array($post, $array_from_db);
```

This will aways create a new array instead of using the container.

For your code:

```
// declare a container
$container = array();
$post = array();
$post['sch_name'] = test_input($sch_name);
$post['sch_degree'] = test_input($sch_degree);
$post['sch_field'] = test_input($sch_field);
$post['sch_grade'] = test_input($sch_grade);
$post['sch_from_year'] = test_input($sch_from_year);
$post['sch_to_year'] = test_input($sch_to_year);
$post['sch_desc'] = test_input($sch_desc);


// push $post and $array_from_db to the $container
array_push($container,$post,$array_from_db);
```

BTW, if you just want to add a new element to the array, you can simply use this:

```
$container[] = $myElement;
```

It saves calling a function (array_push).